# How can I to visualize the diagram of A = (0,1) × (0,1) and B =[ 1,2) × (0,1)?

Tags: geometry

What is the is diagram of A = (0,1) × (0,1) and B =[ 1,2) × (0,1) in $R^{2}$?
How  can i visualise this diagram? how can i plott this graph ?
 My thinking  is that[image]

as i cannot able to Visualize the diagram..pliz help me ,,,

Answer (score 0):

$(0,1)$ is the open interval from $0$ to $1$ so $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ is the unit square missing its sides.  The way I know to plot this is to draw the square and make the sides dashed lines to indicate they are not included.  $[1,2)$ is the interval from $1$ to $2$ including $1$ but not $2$, so $[1,2) \times (0,1)$ is the unit square shifted right by one unit and including the left edge but none of the others, so draw that edge solid and the other ones dashed.